# Hide files that were recently viewed

Tags: ubuntu, unity

I am using Ubuntu 14.10 LTS version on my laptop. When I press the 'windows' key, an interface (probably called a Dash) opens that displays various applications, videos, recent files etc on different tabs.

How to avoid recent files (be it pdfs, documents or video files) from being displayed on this Dash?

Comment: `14.10` is not an LTS release. `14.04` is.

Answer (score 1):

The recent items list used in Ubuntu Unity like below, shows all kind of recently accessed files:

[image]

You can be disable the recording of such activity by adjusting the **Privacy** parameters, by turning OFF the 'Record Activity':

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to **~/.local > share > zeitgeist** and delete the file named **'activity.sqlite'.**

Now logout and back in to see the effect.